# Flex to Change NetStream.Publish perameter from save to publish

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, flex4.5

I am implementing one live audio video web app using flex sdk. I have successfully created a feature, where user can start a live sharing of web cam with others. But i want to add a feature where user can change live streaming to record a video in between a live sharing. Below is a code that i am using in live streaming.

```
var room_service:RoomService = RoomService.getInstance();       
                var publishStream:NetStream =   room_service.startStream();
                _publishStream = publishStream;

                if(_camera)
                {
                    _camera.setQuality(0, 80);
                    _camera.setMode(120, 90, 30);
                    publishStream.attachCamera(_camera);
                }

                if(_microphone)
                {
                    publishStream.attachAudio(_microphone);
                }

                publishStream.publish(room_service.loggedInUser.broadcastID, "live");
```

is there any way i can change the last line "live" perameter to "record" while the stream being publish.